# GWT GoogleMaps API: Multiple Maps with Relative Sizes

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, gwt

I'm using GWT along with the GoogleMaps api wrapper available [here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/list).

I am trying to display 4 GoogleMaps on one page. Each map should take up 25% of the screen. The problem is, it only works if I specify the map sizes as absolute (px), but I need to be able to specify them as relative (percent).

This works fine:

```
package com.test.multimap.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DockLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;


public class GwtMultiMapTest implements EntryPoint {

    DockLayoutPanel mapParent1 = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    DockLayoutPanel mapParent2 = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    DockLayoutPanel mapParent3 = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    DockLayoutPanel mapParent4 = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
    GoogleMap map1;
    GoogleMap map2;
    GoogleMap map3;
    GoogleMap map4;

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        mapParent1.setSize("500px", "500px");
        mapParent2.setSize("500px", "500px");
        mapParent3.setSize("500px", "500px");
        mapParent4.setSize("500px", "500px");
        
        VerticalPanel leftPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        leftPanel.add(mapParent1);
        leftPanel.add(mapParent2);
        
        VerticalPanel rightPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        rightPanel.add(mapParent3);
        rightPanel.add(mapParent4);
        
        HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
        hp.add(leftPanel);
        hp.add(rightPanel);
        
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(hp);

        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMaps();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMaps() {
        
        MapOptions mo1 = MapOptions.create();
        mo1.setZoom(4);
        mo1.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo1.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo1.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map1 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent1.getElement(), mo1);

        MapOptions mo2 = MapOptions.create();
        mo2.setZoom(4);
        mo2.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo2.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo2.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map2 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent2.getElement(), mo2);
        
        MapOptions mo3 = MapOptions.create();
        mo3.setZoom(4);
        mo3.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo3.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo3.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map3 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent3.getElement(), mo3);
        
        MapOptions mo4 = MapOptions.create();
        mo4.setZoom(4);
        mo4.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo4.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo4.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map4 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent4.getElement(), mo4);
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to specify the size of the maps in absolute pixels. I want each map to take up 25% of the screen. But if I do this:

```
mapParent1.setSize("50%", "50%");
mapParent2.setSize("50%", "50%");
mapParent3.setSize("50%", "50%");
mapParent4.setSize("50%", "50%");
```

...then the maps don't show up at all.

### Weirder Still

Through some shotgun debugging, I've come across an approach that works, but only in chrome:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    mapParent1.setSize("100%", "100%");
    mapParent2.setSize("100%", "100%");
    mapParent3.setSize("100%", "100%");
    mapParent4.setSize("100%", "100%");
    
    VerticalPanel leftPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    leftPanel.add(mapParent1);
    leftPanel.add(mapParent2);
    leftPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
    
    VerticalPanel rightPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    rightPanel.add(mapParent3);
    rightPanel.add(mapParent4);
    rightPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
    
    HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp.add(leftPanel);
    hp.add(rightPanel);
    hp.setSize("100%", "100%");
    
    TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2, Unit.EM);
    tabPanel.add(hp, "Maps");
    
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tabPanel);

    AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
    options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
    Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createMaps();
        }
    };
    AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
}
```

If I use this, then it works mostly as you'd expect in chrome. But Internet Explorer is unusably buggy (the maps constantly resize themselves, user input is extremely slow), and firefox just doesn't show anything.

### Questions

- Why can't I specify the size of the maps in percentages?

  - Note that I don't want to specify a parent component's size in pixels either. Each map should take up 25% of the window, and they should grow or shrink when the window is resized.
  - If I **must** specify the size of a parent component (or the maps themselves) using absolute pixels, **why** is that required? Is there a workaround?
- Why does my weird example work in chrome but not in other browsers?

Comment: I'm not sure why somebody voted to close this as too broad. I have specific code that I expect to do one thing, but another thing happens instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using nested `DockLayoutPanels` instead of `VerticalPanels` and `HorizontalPanels`. This works, and I believe it's because `DockLayoutPanel` implements `ProvidesResize`, whereas `VerticalPanel` and `HorizontalPanel` do not.

As for why my weird example works in chrome but not other browsers, I'm still at a loss. If somebody can answer that, I'll unaccept this answer and accept yours instead.

```
package com.test.multimap.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DockLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimpleLayoutPanel;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;


public class GwtMultiMapTest implements EntryPoint {

    DockLayoutPanel parentPanel;

    SimpleLayoutPanel mapParent1 = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    SimpleLayoutPanel mapParent2 = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    SimpleLayoutPanel mapParent3 = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    SimpleLayoutPanel mapParent4 = new SimpleLayoutPanel();
    GoogleMap map1;
    GoogleMap map2;
    GoogleMap map3;
    GoogleMap map4;

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        final DockLayoutPanel leftPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PCT);
        leftPanel.addNorth(mapParent1, 50);
        leftPanel.add(mapParent2);

        final DockLayoutPanel rightPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PCT);
        rightPanel.addNorth(mapParent3, 50);
        rightPanel.add(mapParent4);

        parentPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PCT){
            public void onResize(){
                setWidgetSize(leftPanel, 50);
                leftPanel.setWidgetSize(mapParent1, 50);
                rightPanel.setWidgetSize(mapParent3, 50);
                super.onResize();
            }

        };
        parentPanel.addWest(leftPanel, 50);
        parentPanel.add(rightPanel);

        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(parentPanel);

        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMaps();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMaps() {

        MapOptions mo1 = MapOptions.create();
        mo1.setZoom(4);
        mo1.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo1.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo1.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map1 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent1.getElement(), mo1);

        MapOptions mo2 = MapOptions.create();
        mo2.setZoom(4);
        mo2.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo2.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo2.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map2 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent2.getElement(), mo2);

        MapOptions mo3 = MapOptions.create();
        mo3.setZoom(4);
        mo3.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo3.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo3.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map3 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent3.getElement(), mo3);

        MapOptions mo4 = MapOptions.create();
        mo4.setZoom(4);
        mo4.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mo4.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mo4.setStreetViewControl(false);
        map4 = GoogleMap.create(mapParent4.getElement(), mo4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this problem is inherent when using GoogleMaps on your page.
I remember using another GoogleMaps wrapper and I also had to specify all sizes in px as % doesn't work. 
I have no idea why this is the case.

I would just calculate the widths and heights based, and add a windowResizeHandler to updated the sizes.

Comment: I'll look into how to do that in GWT. Any idea why my weird example works in chrome but not in other browsers?